# Keyboard shortcut using Keys

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, sendkeys

apologies for my basic question but I am a kinda java newbie and I would love to write a code that will do a keyboard shortcut **CTRL + A**.

I have imported:

```
import org.sikuli.hotkey.Keys;
import org.sikuli.script.Key;
```

and wrote a variety of codes similar to this:

```
Keys.CTRL + KeyEvent.VK_A / Keys.A / ...
```

Unfortunately, I did not manage to make it work..

**I have two issues:**

- how to make it work as a keyboard shortcut
- how to add code of an "A"

I have read about the modifiers and tried to find a solution here but without a bit of luck.

I was thinking about adding sth like KeyPress and KeyRelease but idk how to make it work.

Any suggestions?

**Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who is trying to do the same - I think I have found a solution:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

try {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        // Exception
    }
```